# Broken image being displayed when using the image path returned from cordovacapture captureimage

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I have tried various solutions: $cordovaCapture, $cordovaCamera(DATA_URL can display the picture, but i want file_URI to do the same).

here is my code snippet:

```
$scope.addImage = function() {
   var options = {limit: 1};
   $cordovaCapture.captureImage(options).then(function(imageData) {
    console.log(imageData);
     // var jsonobj=angular.toJson(imageData);
       $scope.profile.image = imageData[0];
       console.log(angular.toJson(imageData));
       console.log($scope.profile.image.localURL);//the path to upload
         document.getElementById('myImage').src = "'"+$scope.profile.image.localURL+"'";//have already tried without the quottes
     /* window.plugins.Base64.encodeFile($scope.profile.image.localURL,function(base64){  // Encode URI to Base64 needed for contacts plugin
    $scope.profile.image.preview = base64;
    console.log($scope.profile.image.preview);
});*/
      // Success! Image data is here
    }, function(err) {
    });
```

i even tried whitelisting certainties in the module as in :

```
.config( [
'$compileProvider',
function( $compileProvider )
{ 
$compileProvider.imgSrcSanitizationWhitelist(/^\s*(https?|file|content|blob|cdvfile):|data:image\//);
}
])
```

It didn't help either. I am testing the project in both device and emulator. I even tried base64 encoding the file from the path. Nothing works as to display the recently taken picture. The path that i retrieve is like this:
cdvfile://localhost/persistent/DCIM/Camera/123123123.jpg

Comment: `DATA_URL` return a base64 encoded string, your code is incomplete, where and how do you get the $scope.profile.image.localURL?

Comment: DATA_URL is used as a destinationtype in $cordovaCapture.getPicture which gives the base encoded string and i can display the image with that, the problem is with file_URI i can't get it to display the image. Using file_URI, i have to resolve the path to get the path like : cdvfile://localhost/persistent/DCIM/Camera/123123123.jpg.

If you bind the $scope.profile.image.localURL in the html like {{profile.image.localURL}} you will get the path, furthermore if you log the angular.toJSON(imageData), you will get the many more info, i just extracted the path. I am using cordovaCapture.captureImage.

Comment: but where are you getting the $scope.profile.image.localURL, your code is wrong or incomplete

Comment: i get the path cdvfile://localhost/persistent/DCIM/Camera/123123123.jpg from $scope.profile.image.localURL, all i want is to display that picture, i tried base64 encoding it by com-badrit-base64(cordova plugin) to get the result of data_URL, but to no fruitition, if i could get a working snippet, i could figure something out, but even after massive amount of search, i still can't get the path to work. Anyway, thank you for your valuable comment :)

Comment: the response from $cordovaCapture.getPicture and $cordovaCapture.captureImage is different, the code works perfectly fine, it gives me the path as an output. I have already tried using the file_uri destination type from cordovaCapture and resolving its path results to the path that i get directly from $cordovaCapture.capturePicture.....all i want is to display the picture from the path rather than data....Sorry if i have mislead you with the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `file_URI` to upload the image. I used `data_URL`,converted the image to blob and used the [cordova-file-transfer](http://ngcordova.com/docs/plugins/fileTransfer/) plugin to upload the file to the server. In that way, i could use the base64 encoded image on the html side as well as upload at the same time.

```
 $scope.captureImage = function() {
            navigator.camera.getPicture(cameraSuccess, cameraError, {
                destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL,
                correctOrientation: true
            });
        }

        var cameraSuccess = function(imageData) {
            $scope.profileImageSource = imageData;
            $scope.changeImage = function(base64Data, contentType) {
                contentType = contentType || '';
                var sliceSize = 512;
                var byteCharacters = atob(base64Data);
                var bytesLength = byteCharacters.length;
                var slicesCount = Math.ceil(bytesLength / sliceSize);
                var byteArrays = new Array(slicesCount);

                for (var sliceIndex = 0; sliceIndex < slicesCount; ++sliceIndex) {
                    var begin = sliceIndex * sliceSize;
                    var end = Math.min(begin + sliceSize, bytesLength);

                    var bytes = new Array(end - begin);
                    for (var offset = begin, i = 0; offset < end; ++i, ++offset) {
                        bytes[i] = byteCharacters[offset].charCodeAt(0);
                    }
                    byteArrays[sliceIndex] = new Uint8Array(bytes);
                }
                return new Blob(byteArrays, {
                    type: contentType
                });
            }

            $scope.picture = $scope.changeImage(imageData, 'image/png');
            $scope.$digest();
        }
```

**HTML:**

```
<img ng-src="data:image/gif;base64,{{profileImageSource}}">
```